# Place AdMob fullwidth at the bottom of SDL Android Application

Tags: java, android, admob, sdl-2

I have got my Admob to work on my app after having to gather bits and pieces of information from other articles and some answers here, but my problem is I can't get it to place at the bottom of the page.

I'm really new to android ui xml editing so I just need this to get it to the bottom.

This is my default main.xml layout, no clue how this works and if it is still needed and I would like to place my publisher id in java code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="MyApplication"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm particularly using SDL (SDLActivity.java) so here's the part where it creates the layout

```
    mAdView = new AdView(this);
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    // Set up the surface
    mSurface = new SDLSurface(getApplication());

    mLayout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
    mLayout.addView(mSurface);

    ...

    /*** This is my current setup that works but ads still on top ***/
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    mLayout.addView(mAdView, lay);

    setContentView(mLayout);
```